# Italics doesn't appear on Safari browsers on my site but is fine on Chrome and IE in Windows

Tags: html, css, safari, shopify

I'm customizing my theme and I've run into some cross browser issues that I can't seem to work out. I tried putting normalizer in and no luck.

Everywhere I have italic text on my product pages (on Safari using a tablet and iPhone) it appears as white space, where as on other browsers (I have Windows laptop and Android phone and I use Chrome,) everything is displaying fine.

[This is my product page](https://holy-chic-los-angeles.myshopify.com/collections/preserved-roses/products/petite-cherie-velvet-box)

I'm not sure how to correct this or even test for it if I don't have any Apple products or enough money for these virtual machine services.

How do you go about cross browser compatibility with custom code?

The problem area is in the product description areas below the title, making the price and description display as white space (I'm assuming because they include italics,) and then below the color swatch area I have additional text areas where only the italics appear as white space on those Apple devices, So that is the HTML I'll share as well as my added CSS to this theme.

HTML(product description):

```
    <p class="product-single__price product-single__price-product-template">

          <span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
          <s id="ComparePrice-product-template" class="hide"></s>
          <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-product-template">
            <span id="ProductPrice-product-template" itemprop="price" content="60.0">
              $60.00
            </span>
            <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-product-template hide">Sale</span>
          </span>

      </p>

      <!--    Re-Arranging Product Page & Tabs    -->
      <p><span><strong>Petite Cherie Velvet Box</strong> from the collection Forever and Ever, is really unique and unforgettable! This flower arrangement will last up to 1 year guarantee (usually much longer). This is REAL highest quality preserved flowers. Their beauty and soft delicate touch and appearance make it impossible to differentiate from fresh cut flowers.</span></p>
<p><span>*** <em>Not all pictures correspond with the color of the box. Please ensure to select the color of the box from the drop down menu</em> ***</span></p>
```

HTML(additional text areas):

```
<div class="product-single__description rte" itemprop="description">
      <div>
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li><a href="#tab-1" class="">Care Instructions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-2" class="">Delivery &amp; Shipping</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-3" class="active">Returns &amp; Refunds</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-1" style="display: none;">
          <p>Keep away from water and direct sunlight!</p>
<p>Your roses feel comfortable in their box. Please do not remove them.</p>
<p><i>We feel it is important to mention that all substances used in the preservation process are non-toxic, non-corrosive, non-carcinogenic. The solutions and colorants are the same as those used in food, and textile manufacturing, therefore, they do not represent any health or environmental risk.</i></p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" style="display: none;">
        <p><i>Delivery is only available in the Los Angeles Area, for a flat rate of $25. For same day delivery please place your orders with us by 10:00am.</i></p>

<p>This item ships nationwide. Orders usually ship 24-48 hours within receiving the order.</p>

<p>We will do our best to deliver the product on your desired delivery date. Once your order is in the hands of the carrier we have no control over the delivery process and we recommend you choose a delivery date at least one day early to avoid disappointment.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" style="display: block;">
<!--              -->
        <p>Please choose carefully as we will not be able to offer refund or exchange on any Holy Chic Flower Box due to simple change of mind.</p>

<p>All our arrangements are made to order.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Added + tweaked CSS:

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }

    body #canvas {
        background-color: #fff
    }

    #canvas {
        max-width: 1300px;
        min-width: 350px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    /*     padding: 100px 100px 0 */
        padding: 60px 100px 0;
    }

    #canvas {
        margin: 45px auto;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    }

    #canvas {
      border-width: 2px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:1390px) {
      #canvas {
        margin: 45px auto;
        max-width: 1100px;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
      #canvas {
            margin: 0px auto;
            border-width: 0px !important
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
      #canvas {
            padding: 50px 50px 0
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
      #canvas {
            padding: 0 17px
      }
    }

    #canvas header {
      background: #fff;
    }


    /*================ Nav Adjustments ================*/
    nav.border-bottom {
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

    .site-nav {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 14px;

      /*  Adding Gotham To Nav  */
      font-family: 'Gotham';
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    .site-nav a {
      color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      border-bottom-width: 2px;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 20px;
      line-height: 1.6em;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1087px) and (min-width: 744px) {
        .site-nav a {
            padding: 0px 0px !important;
            margin: 0 15px;
            font-size: 12px !important;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 845px) and (min-width: 744px) {
      .site-nav a{
        margin: 0 8px;
        padding: 0px 0px !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
      }
    }

    .site-nav a:hover {
      color: #111;
      border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }

    .page-divider {
      line-height: 1.6em;
      margin-top: -4.5em;
      margin-bottom: 4.6em;
      font-size: 14px;

      border-bottom-width: 2px;

      border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 869px) {
      .page-divider {
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
      }
    }

    .list--inline li {
      background: #fff;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1087px) {
      .list--inline li {
        margin: 0 -2px;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 648px) {
      .page-divider {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    /*================ Product Page ================*/
    .btn {
      background: #fff !important;
      border: 2px solid #7f7f7f !important;
      color: #7f7f7f !important;
    }
    .btn:hover, .btn:focus {
      background: #7f7f7f !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }

    /*================ Adjustments ================*/
    .main-content {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .search-header {
      display: none;
    }

    /*================ Tabs ================*/
    ul.tabs {
      border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
      margin: 0px 0 10px !important;
    }

    ul.tabs li a {
      font-size: 15px !important;
      padding: 0 10px !important;
      color: #7f7f7f !important;
    }

    ul.tabs li a.active {
      top: -3px !important;
      padding-top: 2px !important;
      color: #4D4D4D !important;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1390px) and (min-width: 1097px) {
      ul.tabs li a {
        font-size: 12px !important;
        padding: 0 7px !important;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1096px) and (min-width: 1025px) {
      ul.tabs li a {
        font-size: 11px !important;
        padding: 0 5px !important;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 985px) {
      ul.tabs li a {
        font-size: 12px !important;
        padding: 0 7px !important;
      }
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 984px) {
      ul.tabs li {
        width: 100% !important;
        text-align: center !important;
      }
      ul.tabs li a {
        font-size: 15px !important;
        padding: 0 10px !important;
      }
    }

    /*================ Changing font================*/
    h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3, h4, .h4, h5, .h5, h6, .h6 {
      font-family: 'Gotham';
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    body, p {
      font-family: 'Gotham';
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      color: #7f7f7f;
    }

    p {
      line-height: 1.8em;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    a {
      color: #7f7f7f;
    }
    /*================ Responsive Adjustments ================*/
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .page-width {
        padding-left: 1px !important;
        padding-right: 1px !important;
      }

      body, html {
        background-color: #fff !important;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 749px) {
      .mobile-nav {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1087px) and (min-width: 576px) {
      .medium-up--one-half {
        width: 50% !important;
      }

      /*  THUMBNAIL SOLUTION  */
      .medium-up--one-quarter {
        width: 25% !important;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
      .medium-up--one-half {
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      /*  PLUGIN RESP. ADJUSTMENT  */
      .swatch {
        margin: 1em 4px !important;
      }
    }

    /*================ Mobile Nav Touch Ups ================*/
    .mobile-nav-wrapper {
      background-color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      left: 0;
    }

    .mobile-nav__item.border-bottom {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    .mobile-nav__link {
      color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    :focus {
      outline: transparent auto 1px;
    }

    .mobile-nav-wrapper::after {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1087px) and (min-width: 744px) {
      .site-nav {
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
    }

    /*================ Mobile Product Page Touch Ups ================*/
    .btn.thumbnails-slider__btn {
      background: #fff !important;
      color: #7f7f7f !important;
      border: 2px solid #fff !important;
    }

    /*================ Hero Img Touch Ups ================*/
    .box {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your styles?

Comment: This question will have _zero value_ to future visitors, because you've only provided a link to your site.  Which will _absolutely_ change in the future in some way that makes this question useless.  Please add the relevant code (HTML / CSS) to your question.

Comment: @cale_b Indeed! Please excuse me for not thinking about that. I added relevant code.

Comment: @stybl Code added, I'm about to try adding the italic versions of my font to the font-face as well.